# How can I add/ remove cipher suites from Schannel without affecting other processes?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, block-cipher

How can I add/ remove cipher suites from Schannel by calling API "BCryptAddContextFunction" and "BCryptRemoveContextFunction" without affecting other processes?

For example, if process 'A' calls those API and changes Cipher suites then other processes such as 'B' or 'C' should not affect that means 'B' or 'C' should be able to use default cipher suites.

I have written following code which was affecting other processes as well.

```
uint status = ERROR_SUCCESS;

status = BCryptRemoveContextFunction(CRYPT_LOCAL,
                                    "SSL",
                                    NCRYPT_SCHANNEL_INTERFACE,
                                    "TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA");
```

Actually I wanted to block weak cipher suites for my client application while communicating with Server using TLS 1.2 but the problem is whatever I have set it was also affecting other applications. How can I block weak cipher suites only for my application without affecting others.

Note: My application is written in C# and I am calling these API using P/Invoke.

Comment: Well, it should be obvious that you cannot use that function, the first parameter is either `CRYPT_LOCAL` to affect the current machine, or `CRYPT_DOMAIN`, which presumably would affect all machines in the domain, if it weren't reserved.

Comment: Thanks Ben for quick response. Can you please suggest, what API can I use to remove weak cipher suites for my application without affecting other applications.

Comment: can anyone suggest me how can I remove weak cipher suites for my application without affecting other applications? I need to implement as soon as possible.

Comment: Hello, after a long time! I was faced with the same problem; Were you able to solve it? If yes, what way did you use? (I am using .NetFramework version 4.8 and it is not possible to upgrade the version).
Thank you.